# How to read through a file and save every four lines in variables of a struct

Tags: c++

I'm still pretty damn new at c++ and coding and general, so bear with me.

So recently in my computer science class I've been asked to make a program that acts as a phone book, being able to save information for different contacts, such as their name, address, phone number, and email.

The phone book would be organized like:

Name

Address

Phone number

email

Name 2

Address 2

Phone number 2

email 2

So you would be able to predict which line holds which information, and hold it in a vector of a struct. My code is as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Contact {
string name;
string address;
string phone;
string email;
};

string line;

vector<Contact> contacts;

int main(){

    ifstream phonebook;

    phonebook.open("phonebook.txt");


    if (phonebook.is_open()){

        int counter = 0;
        int contactCounter = 0;

            while( getline(phonebook,line) ){

                //cout << "line is " << line;
                if(line.length()<=0){
                    cout << "In the if";
                }else{
                    if(counter % 4 == 0){
                        contacts[contactCounter].name = line;
                        cout << counter;
                    }else if(counter % 4 == 1){
                        contacts[contactCounter].address = line;
                    }else if(counter % 4 == 2){
                        contacts[contactCounter].phone = line;
                    }else if(counter % 4 == 3){
                        contacts[contactCounter].email = line;
                        contactCounter++;
                    }

                }
                counter++;
            }
        } else cout << "an error has occurred in opening the contact list";

    cout << "Address of contacts[0]: " << contacts[0].address; //a test to see if it worked

    return 0;

    }
```

(I also have a pre-made text file to test it)
But every time I run the program it stalls out and then quits. Any info? Sorry that I'm not able to explain my thought process that well.

Comment: You should be loading a single `Contact contact;`, then `contacts.push_back(contact)` once you know you have a complete-read for that record. Right now you're invoking UB by indexing your vector out of range. In other words: `contacts[contactCounter]` should not appear in this code *at all*.

Answer (score 2):

Your vector is created empty here: `vector<Contact> contacts;`. You need to `push_back` (or `emplace_back` if you are not on legacy C++ and are allowed to change your class definition to include a user-defined constructor) every new element to it.